# Align Footer (with space) always on the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have two sections.

- The first one contains content of the imprint: company-section.
- The second one is the footer: footer-section, which should always be on the bottom. So I want to create space between them.

I tried to add `margin-bottom: auto;` to my `company-section` but it's not working.

```css
#company-section{
    display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
}
.company-alignment {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1240px;
}



#footer-section {
    display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}

#login-section {
margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<body id="login-section">
    <section id="company-section">
        <div class="company-alignment">
            <p>Imprint</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="footer-section">
    Hi
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the body element to a flex container with a column direction. The #company-section is set to take up the available space using flex: 1, and the #footer-section is pushed to the bottom using margin-top: auto. This will create the required layout with space between the two sections and the footer always at the bottom.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Ensure the body takes at least the full height of the viewport */
}

#company-section {
    flex: 1; /* Allow #company-section to take up remaining space */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#footer-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: auto; /* Push #footer-section to the bottom */
}
```